# If something was broken apart and put back together again, is it intact?

Tags: meaning

Does "intact" cover things that were, but no longer are, broken? If yes, what word should I use to mean only things that were never broken?

Also, if it's scratched or dented but whole, is it intact?

Comment: 'Intact' literally means 'untouched', so I would not describe a repaired, or scratched, object as intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retain the description 'intact' the object must have the appearance of never having been touched, so any blemish or damage causes it to lose its intact state.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/97316?redirectedFrom=intact#eid)

> Etymology: < Latin intactus, < in- (in- prefix3) + tactus, past participle of tangĕre... (Show More)
>   Thesaurus »
>
> Untouched; not affected by anything that injures, diminishes, or sullies; kept or left entire; unblemished; unimpaired.

c1450   Mirour Saluacioun 4966   Thi maydenhode intacte inmaculat eurelastinge.
1721   in N. Bailey Universal Etymol. Eng. Dict.
1815   J. W. Croker in L. J. Jennings Croker Papers (1884) I. iii. 67   No mischief..had been done, except to one old china jar..The gallery was perfectly intact.
a1862   H. T. Buckle Hist. Civilisation Eng. (1869) III. ii. 86   The principles on which Church authority is based remained intact.
1878   A. K. Johnston Africa v. 62   Tunis..has retained the character of an oriental city almost intact.